# Linear correction for projectile

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile, aerodynamics

I am working on a forward model for 3D projectile motion which includes effects from constant wind and Magnus force from spin which changes as a function of time. The input to the model is launch vector and spin axis/angle. This part of the model is done and works as expected.

However, the modeled final positions of the projectile (or rather their positions as they cross an arbitrary plane) differ from known locations substantially. This is certainly due to the limitations of the assumptions of my model.

So I am looking to insert a simple linear correction to my model which would shift the projectile's path so that it crosses the arbitrary plane coincident with the known location.

**How do I apply a linear correction so the projectile's trajectory passes through the known location?**

Do I forward model the trajectory, collect the 3D points, and then apply the correction? Or can I include a translation that vary's as a function of the distance perpendicular to the arbitrary plane?

This forward model will be run several million times, so some consideration for a computationally efficient solution will be useful.

Comment: You should apply a constant force that acts over the course of the trajectory. Do you wish to apply the same correction to all projectiles, i.e. irrespective of initial conditions? Or will you compute the correction for each individual projectile?

Comment: Correction would need to be per-projectile. My question is really asking how do I compute the constant correction "force".

Comment: I wonder whether you shouldn't first consider improving the physics model, before adding a fudge factor. How are you modeling drag? Surface properties? Do you know how rapidly the spin changes (axis, rate of rotation)? Are your objects perfectly spherical (shape and mass distribution)? How large are the errors - and how small are you trying to make them?

Comment: I am approaching the best physics model using the data I can acquire. I am assuming constant drag based on experimental observations of the projectile. Spin axis and rate changes are measured directly by radar and included. Objects are pseudo-spherical with radially symmetric distribution mass.

There is certainly room for improvement in the physics model if I can get measured error (currently not reported by my radar system). However that will take more time to implement so for the time being I was just looking to make this linear adjustment.

Comment: -1. Unclear.What are the assumptions of your model? Exactly what "part 
 of the model... works as expected"? I think you can only add a linear correction in some parameter (such as flight time) if the discrepancy is linear in that parameter - this needs to be tested. ... I agree with Floris : better to try working out why the discrepancy occurs when you are taking account of wind, Magnus effect and presumably also drag.

Comment: I am assuming constant wind speed and direction over a 3+ hour period due to limitations of my data. So extreme accuracy is out of the question. The linear correction worked just fine for my application. Better than expected actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways to do this, depending on your needs.

**Corrective displacement**

You could run the simulation without any correction to generate the trajectory $\vec{x}(t)$. Suppose the error between the final position and the target is $\vec{e}$, then you can add a linear displacement to the trajectory:

$$\vec{x}(t) \rightarrow \vec{x}(t) + \vec{e}\frac{t}{T}$$

where $T$ is the time-of-flight of the trajectory. However, this approach is effectively changing the velocity of the trajectory without correctly modifying the Magnus force so it would only be suitable if $\vec{e}$ is reasonably small (or if you don't care *too* much about the physics).

**Corrective force**

This would be more physically sound but is more complicated: apply a constant force $\vec{f}$ to the trajectory during the entire flight. However, since you have the Magnus force acting, I don't see an analytical way to compute $\vec{f}$ (but I could be wrong), in which case you will need to solve it numerically, i.e. by finding $\vec{f}$ that minimises $|\vec{e}|$ but without derivatives. There are lots of methods for tackling this, see [Wikipedia: Derivative-free optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative-free_optimization). Personally I would use [coordinate descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_descent) for this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used the corrective displacement. Instead of using the e(x,y,z) for the final position and T as the total time, I used the position and elapsed time for the point closest to my arbitrary plane.